# This code has a bug

Tags: c, debugging

I am a beginner level problem solver in [this online judge](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br). I did pretty good in first 20 problems. But in no. [21](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1021) I got stuck. I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double notes[] = {100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2};
    double moedas[] = {1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01};
    int amount_of_notes[6];
    int amount_of_moedas[6];
    double n, x;
    int i, j;
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    printf("NOTAS: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        x = fmod(n, notes[i]);
        amount_of_notes[i] = n/notes[i];
        n = x;
        printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %.2lf\n", amount_of_notes[i], notes[i]);
    }
    printf("MOEDAS: \n");
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        amount_of_moedas[j] = n/moedas[j];
        x = fmod(n, moedas[j]);
        n = x;
        printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ %.2lf\n", amount_of_moedas[j], moedas[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is in C. This code converts a number to some banknotes & coins. But when I input `54.54` the output comes like this:

```
NOTAS: 
0 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
2 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS: 
0 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
3 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```

as you can see that in the last line only `3` shows where it should be showing `4`. I tried so hard to find the bug in the code. I failed. Please help find the bug of this code!!

Comment: floating point computation isn't adapted to this case. Use cents with integer computation and divide by 100 in the end.

Comment: Please give your question a better title.

Comment: `n/notes[i];` --> `lrint(n/notes[i])`

Comment: All these seem to start with 'float' or 'double' ;(

Answer (score 1):

Avoid floating point variables for anything that requires precision. Floats are not precise and you will face rounding errors. In your case, you expect 4 but get 3 due to rounding errors.

Instead do all calculations using integers and use cents as the base unit.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int notes[] = {10000, 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200}; // Unit is cents
    int moedas[] = {100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 1};            // Unit is cents
    int amount_of_notes[6];
    int amount_of_moedas[6];
    double n;
    int x;
    int n_int;
    int i, j;
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    n_int = 100 * n;                                  // Unit is cents
    printf("NOTAS: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        x = n_int / notes[i];
        amount_of_notes[i] = x;
        n_int -= x * notes[i];
        printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %.2lf\n", amount_of_notes[i], notes[i]/100.0);
    }
    printf("MOEDAS: \n");
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        x = n_int / moedas[j];
        amount_of_moedas[j] = x;
        n_int -= x * moedas[j];
        printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ %.2lf\n", amount_of_moedas[j], moedas[j]/100.0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
54.54
```

Output:

```
NOTAS: 
0 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
2 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS: 
0 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
4 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to how computers handle floating point numbers. This resource has a good explanation on the topic.

http://floating-point-gui.de/

There are several ways to approach this problem, in your case I believe using integers is the best option. You could start with your "notes" and "moedas" values as integers (multiplying them all by 100) and do the same with the input. This would not change the end result but you would be dealing with integers instead of floating point numbers. And as integers are exact (no rounding errors) the result will be what you expect.

Here there is proof of concept based on your code. Note that I've made just the minimum changes that would make it work, there is a lot of room for improvement.

https://repl.it/Lxg0/2